# How to choose the right Barlow lens?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, eyepiece

I have a OneSky AWB 130 (130 mm aperture) Newtonian telescope w/ 650 mm aperture.

I previously asked a question on another account on what lens to get next--@AaronF suggested that I get the Orion Tri-Mag. However, I've stretched my budget, and can afford an eyepiece that's around $100.

The Orion X-Cel 3x Barlow is an example of something in my price range and has good reviews. I understand that seeing conditions must be very good for a 3.3x magnification to work; additionally, according to the comment mentioned above the Orion Tri-Mag has a 2x magnification, which can work better on nights with poorer seeing condition.

This is the current extent of my research, what other factors should I consider?

Comment: "Images provided in reviews".. you will never know what telescope they have used. the quality of the image depends mostly on the telescope and partly on the eyepieces. remember the limitation of use of the barlow w.r.t your telescope (magnification) instead buy the astromaster kit which gives 2x barlow and 2 eyepieces which are of good quality to make the best use.

Comment: @KavinIshwaran "you will never know what telescope they have used..." Unless they tell you. The astromaster kit seems to be of somewhat average quality.

Comment: I personally own one for one of my reflectors, the barlow is good for its standards and I never faced any issue with the images. I personally consider it over x-cel

Comment: I've edited your question because "Which one of the two should I get, and do you have any other suggestions?" is a "shopping question" and those are strongly discouraged and usually quickly closed. Also, you mention another question you've asked "on another account" 1) can you add a link to that question so readers can review what's there? 2) just fyi if you are interested, there are ways to merge two accounts if you are interested.

Comment: Hi again! :-) I, personally, would get the cheaper Barlow and put the extra money towards a nice new eyepiece - like a Baader Morpheus 9mm (to replace the bundled 10mm). I would do this because I found that I used my Barlow much less once I bought more eyepieces. The Barlow is very useful while you don't have many eyepieces, but it's a waypoint on a longer journey.

Comment: Oh, well, oops. I just ordered a 2x and 3x--the Celestron X-Cel 3x and the Celestron Omni 2x. I hope I can still get good results.